# How to make Image_load_store work (reading from image in pixel shader)

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl

I'm writing Win32 app using https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store - I want to read a value from the texture attached to Pixel shader (and once it's working, I will change operation to write). I'm using GLFW and GLEW, the supported OGL version of my gfx card is 4.2. The relevant texture setup code looks like this:

```
typedef unsigned int BufferType;
int buf_w = 3;
int buf_h = 3;
int buf_size = buf_w * buf_h;

BufferType * bufferCounter = new BufferType[buf_size];
for (int i = 0; i < buf_size; ++i) 
    bufferCounter[i] = 200;

glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

glGenTextures( 1, &tex2d );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2d );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0 );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0 );

glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32UI, buf_w, buf_h, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, bufferCounter );
```

Main loop:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(shader_program);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2d );

glBindImageTexture( 0, tex2d, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_ONLY, GL_R32UI ); // bind 2d tex to read_tex
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Vertex shader is irrelevant, just gl_Position = vec4 (vertex_position, 1.0); Fragment shader:

```
#version 430
#extension ARB_shader_image_load_store : enable

in vec3 color;
out vec4 frag_color;

readonly layout(r8ui) uniform uimage2D read_tex;

void main() 
{
 frag_color = imageLoad(read_tex, ivec2(0,0) ); // read from attached tex
}
```

I check with glGetError - no errors. Also shaders compile and link. The triangle isn't visible on the screen (but if I set color to constant, it is). Any ideas on what might be wrong? I tried using in main loop functions `loc = glGetUniformLocation( shader_program, "read_tex" ); glUniform1i( loc, tex2d );` but they didn't help. Thank you for help. Unfortunately I couldn't find any example on how to use this OGL functionality, and the documentation is scarce.

Comment: Shouldn't it be r32ui in the shader? and you should add a binding=0 to ensure that read_tex points to image unit 0. `readonly layout(r32ui, binding=0) uniform...`

Comment: I tried r32ui, and added binding but no change. However, after adding glUniform1i( loc, 0 ) before glBindImageTexture() I can read value from .r and .a :) Which is curious, but a base to improve the test. Thank you!

Comment: since it is a one-channel texture, .r should be the correct operator to go.